# Open cmd on remote computer from ssh

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh

I have a windows machine that I can connect to using SSH from my RasPi.
I'd like to have a cmd shell open on the windows machine (initiated from the SSH) so that I can monitor it from the windows machine after the ssh connection is closed

I've tried using `start cmd /k launch.bat` but this just runs the .bat in the ssh connection.

Clarity: It's like a run it remotely from the rpi and check it on the windows machine when I get home situation

Answer (score 1):

You can look into programs like `screen` or `tmux`. They allow you to start a shell in a virtual screen that you can then also view from any other shell (e.g., on the host computer)

Comment: The question appears to be asking about opening a ``CMD.EXE`` window, running on the Windows computer.

Comment: The intention is to monitor the commands run from the rpi on the windows machine?

Comment: Thanks for the help but I was more asking what Scott suggested as once the CMD window is opened and executing the command, it will only be monitored from the windows machine. (It's sort of a start it remotely from the rpi and check it on the windows machine when I get home situation)

Comment: Got it. While this is still possible using the tools I mentioned, they are likely not a perfect fit. Using them requires you to open the cmd.exe window yourself to attach to the remotely-launched shell (The window will not open on its own).

Answer (score 0):

You can run locally:

```
start cmd.exe @cmd /k "echo Hello"
```

If I connect to my user account over ssh I can not run start. I can run:

```
"C:\Program Files\PSTools\PsExec.exe" -s -i cmd.exe @cmd /k "echo Hello"
```

I have installed the [PsTools](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/pstools) to `C:\Program Files\PSTools`. To open the cmd as a new window you have to use start which will not work with SSH.

But instead you can run it from remote as local process. For that you have to disable `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA` to `0` and restart your system.

Then you can run:

```
"C:\Program Files\PSTools\PsExec.exe" -s -i 1 "C:\Windows\System32\cmd" @cmd /k "echo Hello World"
```